# Importing a CSV with EWKB field into Postgres

Tags: postgis, postgresql, import, well-known-binary

I have a csv that I'm trying to import in postgres with postgis enabled but can't seem to get the EWKB field to work. I have created a table:

CREATE TABLE sample_data (
    id character varying(200) NOT NULL,
    uid character varying(200) NOT NULL,
    point_geom geometry(Point,4326) NOT NULL);

and then copied the data from the csv into it:

COPY sample_data FROM 'D:/Workspace/sample_data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;

Sample CSV:
"id","uid","point_geom"
"1953642","12359234","0101000020E610000030629F008AB937407D2079E750FC4240"

Error I get from Postgres is:
ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
SQL state: XX000
Hint: "point_g" <-- parse error at position 7 within geometry
Context: COPY sample_data, line 1, column point_geom: "point_geom"

Anyone have any ideas? That error is not exactly the clearest to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostGIS is reporting a parse error because it's reading the header row and trying to parse the text "point_geom" as a geometry.  You can instruct `COPY` to skip the header row by adding the `HEADER` flag to your command:

```
COPY sample_data FROM 'D:/Workspace/sample_data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: That got it. Thanks man that was driving me up a wall.